# Add attention mechanism to classification problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attention-model

Currently, I am trying to implement attention mechanism to (sequence frame) video classification. So I am implementing the attention between CNN (feature extraction) -> attention -> LSTM (classification to specific class). I followed two papers for the implementation: "Action Recognition using visual attention" and "Show, Attend and Tell: Neural Image Caption Generation with Visual Attention".

I have an image classification CNN and would like to extract the features and put it into a LSTM to visualize soft attention.

After the last FC layer from a trained CNN, I extracted the features. After that, I applied attention to train attention weights and LSTM for classification. The goal of the. attention model is to know where the model is looking when it predicts specific class. So need to implement a spatial attention module for saliency detection

```
base_model = load_model(weight_file) // A trained resnet model
last_conv_layer = base_model.get_layer("global_average_pooling2d_3")
cnn_model = Model(input=base_model.input,output=last_conv_layer.output)
cnn_model.trainable = False

inputs = Input(shape=(max_frames, h, w, 3)) 
x = TimeDistributed(cnn_model)(inputs)
attention = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(x)
attention = Flatten()(attention)
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
attention = RepeatVector(256)(attention)
attention = Permute([2, 1])(attention)

sent_representation = merge([x, attention], mode='mul')       
x = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(sent_representation)

predictions = Dense(101, activation='softmax', name='pred')(x)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "train.py", line 210, in 
>      train_model(X,y,weight_file)
>    File "train.py", line 62, in train_model
>      model = lrcn_model(Nframes,H,W,weight_file)
>    File "/models.py", line 71, in lrcn_model
>      sent_representation = merge([x, attention], mode='mul')
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Is this a correct implementation of the attention mechanism? And how can I fix the issue above that I am getting?

Comment: have you implemented attention mechanism for video classification?

Comment: @donto No, Struggling with adding the attention mechanism to a trained network.